# Facebook API: private messages of a page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to access the private messages that were sent to my FB **page**. I've been looking for a way to do this, but a lot of information is already very old.

I'm currently using `/conversations` but this only returns the link to a chat. I just want the content of that message and be able to answer that message.

I've read somewhere (but this post was also kind of old) that there is no way to do this. Is this still the case in 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would be the endpoint to get the messages of a specific conversation:

```
/{conversation-id}/messages
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/conversation/messages/#read

Time based paging with the "since" parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Comment: > This document refers to a feature that was removed after Grafiek API v2.5.

Comment: just try it, that message pops up in a lot of places. it´s a bug.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter like "since"? I only want the private messages from a certain date.

Comment: i added a link to time based paging docs for the since parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that. But honestly, I find this documentation confusing. When I'm trying to user the "since" field, I get `Unknown fields: since=`

Comment: hard to help without knowing what exactly you have tried ;) - it is also possible that this is not possible at all for conversations.

Comment: I've used "since" the same way that I did with - so to speak - 100 other examples where it **did** work. So I guess it's not supported for conversations indeed. But when I have 10000 conversations, loadtime will go trough the roof. I just want to get the conversations that were added since the last time I checked. Is there another way to achieve that that you know of?

Comment: just store the id of the last entry. in the next run, read all conversions until you reach that id. since you need paging anyway (because you can´t guarantee to get all item with one call), this is a better solution than using "since", imho.

Comment: Ok, thanks. 1 last question: how many items can fit in 1 page? is it a fixed number?

Comment: no, that´s what the "limit" parameter is for. you should not set it to more than 100 though, it´s kind of buggy. by default, the limit is 25.